# jq: error: test1/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1

Tags: shell, jq

I have below JSON file and facing error when trying to add values to array dynamically in the shell.

Below is a tmp.json file,

```
{
  "environments": {
    "integration": [
      "testing for jenkins job"
    ],
    "prod": [],
    "staging": [],
    "uat": []
  }
}
```

When I try to append values to an array with a static variable, it works fine.
Below is the command,
jq '.environments.integration += ["test1"]' tmp.json

The respective output is,

```
{
  "environments": {
    "appbuild": [],
    "integration": [
      "testing for jenkins job",
      "test1"
    ],
    "prod": [],
    "staging": [],
    "uat": []
  }
 }
```

Whereas when I try to append values dynamically, it throws an error.

```
export Environment_Name="integration"
jq ".environments."\"${Environment_Name}"\" += test1" tmp.json
```

Error I am getting is,

```
jq: error: test1/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.environments."integration" += test1
jq: 1 compile error
```

Can anyone please help to fix this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have some extra quotes in there and `test1` needs to be `["test1"]`

`jq ".environments.${Environment_Name} += [\"test1\"]" tmp.json`

Comment: I have just discovered that for some reason on Windows 10 in Powershell, we need to escape the double quotes even in single quotes, e.g. this does not work without the backslashes (note that `curl.exe` is installed via [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/curl)): `curl.exe -s https://api.github.com/repos/alerque/libertinus/releases/latest | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.content_type == \"application/zip\").browser_download_url'`. Strange.

Answer (score 21):

Using shell-based variable interpolation is usually a very bad idea. In the present case, what if the shell variable contains a double-quotation mark, for example?

The safe thing to do is to use `env` or `--arg` or `--argjson` as appropriate, e.g.

```
jq --arg e "${Environment_Name}" '.environments[$e] += ["test1"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

when I am using jq to check the validity of a json file I use it like this: `cat myfile.json | jq`.

Comment: Why is this necessary? You're right, it is -- but why?